# Profiling in VisualVm Using IntelliJ with Debug

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, visualvm, jvisualvm

I want to profile my test application started by IntelliJ. For profiling I useVisualVm.

I started the java tool with the parameter `-J-Dorg.netbeans.profiler.separateConsole=true`.

I started the application with the VM parameter `-Xverify:none`, otherwise VisualVM throws an error if I start profiling (Redefinition failed with error 62)

I want to profile my application before any important code has beed executed, so I tried to set a break point and start profiling in VisualVM. The problem is that VisualVm doesn't respond to any interaction while I'm waiting at my break point. Do I miss something?

In normal execution (without debugging) my program waits for input, so I can profile it without debugging. But what if a program doesn't has such "waiting points"?

My test application looks like that:

```
package my.visualvm.example;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Starting Application: " + MainClass.class.getSimpleName());

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            double value = scanner.nextDouble();
            if (value == 0d) {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(Powa.powaPowa(value));
        }

        System.out.println("Stopping Application: " + MainClass.class.getSimpleName());
    }

}
```

Other class:

```
package my.visualvm.example;

final class Powa {

    private Powa() {
    }

    static double powaPowa(double powa) {
        return Math.pow(powa, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: [GitHub issue describing this VisualVM problem](https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/issues/427) (currently unresolved)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Set the breakpoint to suspend the current thread only. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I was searching for hours!